# sql query to Select Day of month

Tags: sql

I want a query where the output should be only day of month
for.e.g Consider today's date(04-07-2016).The output should be "04"

I have been trying with multiple queries which returns complete date.Whereas I need simply date(01-30).
please guide for the same.

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using.

Comment: For `SQL SERVER` it should be `SELECT DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())`. Also the second part of the question is no where related to first part

Answer (score 1):

For SQL-Server (using a DateTime column):

```
select datepart(day, datecolumn)
```

For SQL-Server (using today):

```
select datepart(day, getdate())
```

If you want a 2 digit date (`04` and not just `4`), then use this:

```
select right('0' + rtrim(day(getdate())), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the followig

```
  SELECT datepart(dd, GETDATE())
```

It will helps to format the date also.
if you want left pad with zero for single digit then try the following query

```
  SELECT RIGHT('0'+ convert(varchar,datepart(DD, GETDATE())) ,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query for today,

```
SELECT RIGHT('00'+CAST (datepart(DAY, getdate()) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

For a column in DB,

```
SELECT RIGHT('00'+CAST (datepart(DAY, <<YourColumn>>) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) From <<YourTable>>
```